# NetLogo, How can I make the agent move is a specific area and then colour the area while it moving without stucking?

Tags: netlogo

> the problem

In this code I try to make the agent to move in the yellow area which is = 47, and to colour the patches to be "red", but the problem is that the agent stuck in the red coloured area.
I want the agent to move and to colour until all the patches become red, it is like cleaning.
**Please guys, I need help please....**

> ;;leftcheck and rightcheck has been declared in globals

```
if (behaviour = "RCleaner")
  [
    ifelse any? patches in-cone 2 10 with [pcolor = 47]
      [ fd random-float 0.03 ]
      [ 
        rt 2
        ifelse any? patches in-cone 2 10 with [pcolor = 47]
          [ set rightcheck true ] [ set rightcheck false ]
        lt 2
        ifelse any? patches in-cone 2 10 with [pcolor = 47]
          [ set leftcheck true ] [ set leftcheck false ]
        rt 2
        if leftcheck  [ lt 1 ]
        if rightcheck [ rt 1 ]
        fd 0.01 
      ]
      set heading heading  + random 1 - random 1
      ask patch-here [ set pcolor red]
  ]
```

Comment: Please guys, any help pleaaaaaaaaase???

Comment: `random 1` is always 0

Comment: Dear Seth Tisue, can you please clarify more please ? I can't see what you mean.

Comment: Try it in NetLogo. Type `print random 1` in NetLogo's Command Center. It will always print `0`. So when you write `set heading heading + random 1 - random 1`, it's the same as writing `set heading heading + 0 - 0`, which is the same as `set heading heading`, which does exactly nothing. See the definition of `random` at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random